Can I still access the potato dimension?
In reference to this page on the Minecraft Wiki, I was wondering if there is a mod out there so I can access, The Potato? Or am I reading this wrong, and you can play Minecraft: Poisonous Potato by playing one of the Minecraft snapshots?

You mean snapshots?
You can play the update by switching to the 24w14potato snapshot:

Or, if you are on Bedrock, download the addon from the marketplace.

Of course. Mojang wouldn't create a silly mod for just one day, then delete it. I certainly wouldn't.
